# disposing httpClient in aspnetcore mvc controller

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a new Asp.Net Core (net standard 2) Mvc controller that uses a WebAPI (REST) call to obtain the data.  I was following many of the examples shown all over the Interweb from both microsoft and non-microsoft sources.  These all use the "standard"  using(var client = new HttpClient()) construct.
However, then read the documentation for [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-2.0)

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout
>   the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for
>   every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy
>   loads. This will result in SocketException errors. Below is an example
>   using HttpClient correctly.

This got me thinking, do I create a scoped instance and add it to DI, or follow their example on the same page, and create a static instance on the controller?  If a static instance, how do I dispose it?

Alternately, can anyone point me to a production ready MVC wrapper for a standard CRUD view implementation?

Comment: You can still use DI. Simply declare it's lifetime as singleton (or whatever nomenclature your DI uses for single instance instead of scoped) to have the same instance shared by all scopes.

Comment: Just beware if your `httpclient` sits in a service that has `singletone` lifetime and if that service has dependencies on other services then those other services should not be `scoped`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone using **.net core 2.1** or greater it is recommended to use `HttpClientFactory`

To address those mentioned issues and make the management of HttpClient instances easier, .NET Core 2.1 introduced a new HttpClientFactory that can also be used to implement resilient HTTP calls

See [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) on how it can be leveraged.

Answer (score 4):

If you have not read ["You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software"](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

> If you have any kind of load at all you need to remember these two
>   things:
>
> 1. Make your HttpClient static.
> 2. Do not dispose of or wrap your HttpClient in a using unless you explicitly are looking for a particular behavior (such as causing your services to fail).

I agree with `mike z` DI can be used in this case.

e.g. SimpleInjector's [Singleton](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#singleton) is taking care of disposing.

> Simple Injector guarantees that instances are disposed in opposite
>   order of creation.

---

If you still want to wrap it, look at ["Generic wrapper for calling ASP.NET WEB API REST service using HttpClient with optional HMAC authentication"](http://codehelper.net/web-api/generic-wrapper-for-calling-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-using-httpclient-with-optional-hmac-authentication/)

**Upd:** 
Make sure you dispose of instances of both of `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage`. [See example of usage](https://github.com/FacilityApi/FacilityCSharp/commit/c151d4cb397c3667c8741fa89f0c737e29914042?w=1)

Source: http://faithlife.codes/blog/2017/03/usage-guidelines-for-httpclient/

Comment: How about `HttpResponseMessage`? Shoudl we `Dispose()` or not?

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek, you should dispose of instances of both classes `HttpRequestMeesage` and `HttpResponseMessage`

example: https://github.com/FacilityApi/FacilityCSharp/commit/c151d4cb397c3667c8741fa89f0c737e29914042?w=1
Src: http://faithlife.codes/blog/2017/03/usage-guidelines-for-httpclient/

Comment: makes sense. What if you don't have a `HttpRequestMessage` because you use `GetAsync(string requestUri)` override? Is it disposed somehow?

Comment: If you want a full control, use `SendAsync()` instead of wrappers like `GetAsync()`, `PostAsyc()` etc. In case of `GetAsync()` it should not be an issue, because HTTP GET is limited by 2k. So GC will take care of it. [Source Code of HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs)

Comment: That make sense. Anyway, how is the max request length connected to Dispose? Thank you.

Comment: My prev comment has 3 points: (1) use SendAsync to get full control. 
In case of using `GetAsync` it creates `HttpRequestMessage` internally and it does not use unmanaged resources so (3) GC will take care of it (it should not be your headache). (2) Because of max request limit, it's negligible this case.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I got it now. Thanks for clarification.